# How to use buttons to manipulate values

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a calculator as a learning project for myself.I am able to display the numeric values onto the screen of the calcultor. But cant seem to figure out how to use the basic operator buttons with the numeric buttons together to display the value.

I tried targeting the different different buttons to get an output but had no luck.

Could someone please explain some different methods that I could use to resolve the issue?

```js
// display of calculor
let screen= document.getElementById("display");

// addition button
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");




// displays on the calculator
function diplays(){
    for(let button of buttons){
        button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        screen.value += e.target.value;
        })}
        
}
// button that adds values on calculator
function add(){
    let plus = document.querySelector(".plus");
    // event listener on the addition button
    plus.addEventListener("click",function(e){



    })
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <div class="container">§
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="display">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons1">
            <button class="size seven" value="7">7</button>
            <button class="size eight" value ="8">8</button>
            <button class="size nine" value ="9">9</button>
            <button class="size negative" >+/-</button>
            <button class="size arrow">→</button>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons1">
            <button class="size four" value="4">4</button>
            <button class="size five" value ="5">5</button>
            <button class="size six " value="6">6</button>
            <button class="size multiply">×</button>
            <button class="size divide">÷</button>
            <div>

<div class="buttons2">
    <button class="size one" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="size two" value="2">2</button>
    <button class="size three" value="3">3</button>
    <button class="size minus">-</button>
</div>
<div class="buttons2">
    <button class="size clear">C</button>
    <button class="size zero" value="0">0</button>
    <button class="size dot" >.</button>
    <button class="size plus">+</button>
    <button class="size equals">=</button>

</div>
        
  </div>
    
</body>
<script src="calculator.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing is allowed after the closing `body` tag, except the closing `html` tag. Your `script` reference should be just before the closing `body` tag. Also, when I try your buttons, nothing at all happens.

Comment: Your functions add event listeners but are never called. Add diplays() and add() in your script so that the listeners are effective.

Comment: You also have an opening `div` instead of a closing `div` at the end of `buttons1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a lot of HTML and JavaScript that isn't needed and really just bloats up the code. While I haven't written a complete solution below, I have re-worked this into a structure that should give you the right idea on how to move forward.

See the HTML and JavaScript comments for details.

```js
let output = document.getElementById("display");

// Just set up one event handler at the container level
// All events will bubble up to that element and can be
// handled there
document.querySelector(".calculator").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // You can determine which, specific element triggered the event
  // by looking at event.target and then you can work with that
  // element's classes, with the .classList property. This will
  // allow you to figure out what kind of button was clicked
  // and act accordingly
  
  // There are other more elegant and concise ways of doing the 
  // following, but this way makes it very clear and easy to follow:
  if(event.target.classList.contains("number") || event.target.classList.contains("dot")){
    // Put the number in the display
    // You don't need the HTML buttons to have a value attribute,
    // you can just get the text that is in the button.
    output.textContent += event.target.textContent;
  } else if(event.target.classList.contains("operation")) {
      // Determine which operation needs to be performed
      switch (event.target.textContent) {
        case "+":
          // do addition here
          console.log("Addition");
          break;
        case "-":
          // do subtraction here
          console.log("Subtraction");
          break;
        case "×":
          // do multiplication here
          console.log("Multiplication");
          break;
        case "÷":
          // do Division here
          console.log("Division");
          break;          
      }
  }

});
```

```css
/* We can make just about any HTML element look like a textbox
   without it being one. Since you are only displaying the results
   of the calculator, a textbox isn't needed. */
#display { 
  border:1px solid grey; 
  background:#E0E0E0; 
  width:100px; 
  height:1em; 
  display:inline-block; 
}

.calculator button { width: 25px; height:25px; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <div class="calculator">
    <div>
      <!-- You shouln't use an input element for output. -->
      §<span id="display"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- The buttons should fall into general classifications (classes)
           rather than have a specific class that only pertains to it. 
           Also, you don't need to assign a value attribute to the buttons.
           Instead, you can just extract the text of the button. 
           One goal of writing HTML is to keep it as simple and clean as possible. -->
      <button class="number">7</button>
      <button class="number">8</button>
      <button class="number">9</button>
      <button class="operation">+/-</button>
      <button class="operation">→</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="number">4</button>
      <button class="number">5</button>
      <button class="number">6</button>
      <button class="operation">×</button>
      <button class="operation">÷</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="number">1</button>
      <button class="number">2</button>
      <button class="number">3</button>
      <button class="operation">-</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="operation">C</button>
      <button class="number">0</button>
      <button class="dot" >.</button>
      <button class="operation">+</button>
      <button class="operation">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="calculator.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for feedback will try a different approach to the one i have.